# Dojo : ComboBox is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, combobox, dojo

I am writing on a JavaScript application which uses the `dojo Toolkit`. I have made a folder in the dojo folder called "md" (My Dojo). There are 2 .js files in there `myownclass.js` and `myComboBox.js` . `myownclass.js` is for retrieving Informations from a `SQLite` Database by making a dojo Request (works) to `sqlaccess.php` . firebug is telling me that the request is correct. But the function does not want to go to the function `prepare_str(str)` and push the string to the Array data : [].

data : [],

```
constructor : function( ){
        this.getdata();
    },

    //gets Data
getdata : function(){
    xhr("sqlaccess.php?order=0").then(function(text){
                                                                                    this.prepare_str(text.toString().split(";"));});
        return this.data;
    },
    //push Data to Array    
prepare_str : function(str){
    alert(str);
    for(var index = 0; index < str.length; index++)
    {
        data.push({name:str[index], id: index});
    }
    //get
    },
```

the full code you can see in: http://pastebin.com/aKUrLmcH

and the other error is in `myComboBox.js` where it tells me that new ComboBox() is not a constructor

```
MyMemory : null,
        comboBox : null,
        //keyhandle : null,

        oldval : "",
        constructor: function(){
            this.MyMemory = new myownclass();
            var stateStore = new Memory({data : this.MyMemory.data});
            comboBox = new ComboBox({
                            id: "stateSelect",
                            name: "state",
                            value: "",
                            store: stateStore,
                        searchAttr: "name"
                        }, "stateSelect");
                var handle = on(dom.byId("stateSelect"),"keyup", this.keyupfoo);        
            },
```

the full code is readable here: http://pastebin.com/hi8nkymf

Can anyone see the error I am making?

Thanks for help

Comment: did you add that in the require section?

Comment: now I could correct the error ComboBox is not a constructor. But it still won't push the request result to array. this.MyMemory.data is still emptry :(

Comment: It seems that the xhr("sqlaccess.php?order=0").then(function(text){ /*Do something*/}); that the value of text cannot be pushed outside of this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem, with the `prepare_str()` function not being called is due to a scoping issue. When you rely on a callback, then `this` will no longer refer to your class. To solve that you could use the [`hitch()`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dojo/_base/lang#1_9dojo__base_lang_hitch) method of the **dojo/_base/lang** module, for example:

```
xhr("sqlaccess.php?order=0").then(lang.hitch(this, function(text){
    this.prepare_str(text.toString().split(";"));
}));
```

This makes sure that the callback of the `xhr()` function will use the current object as scope and so `this` will refer to your class (which contains the `prepare_str()` function).

---

I'm not sure why your combobox is not working though. Make sure the module is being loaded correctly and also note that in your constructor of your `myComboBox` you should not forget to use the `this`.

```
this.comboBox = new ComboBox({
    id: "stateSelect",
    name: "state",
    value: "",
    store: stateStore,
    searchAttr: "name"
}, "stateSelect");
```

If you want further help with your constructor problem, you should try to make a screenshot of the console where your error is or at least give the full stacktrace of the error (I'm assuming it's located at the `new ComboBox()` statement, but I want to be sure.